# How to rotate an image in GNU Octave?

Tags: image-processing, octave

```
I = imread("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/download.jpg");
dir = [1 0 0]
J = rotate(I,dir,90);
```

This is the code i have written. but it doesnt seem to work.
Is there any direct command to rotate an image by say 45 degree or 90 degree.

it gives the following errors:

```
rotate: H must be an array of one or more graphics handles
```

I am new to image processing. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean "it doesnt seem to work"? What is your output after the rotation?

Comment: @DrBwts I have updated the question to show the error that the code gives

Comment: As stated in the tag descriptions, "Don’t use both the [matlab] and [octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two."

Comment: Reading the documentation would have saved you the effort of posting a question, and all the folks here the effort of reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rotate(h, dir, alpha)` is for rotating graphical objects ie obects that are defined by sets of coordinates eg grids, surfaces etc...

To rotate images you need to use [imrotate()](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/imrotate.html)

Comment: How exactly do I pass the parameters for the imrotate() command. I found the command but didnt realise what are the arguments to be passed. Any help with regards to the arguments would be appreciated

Comment: errr did you click the link and read the documetation? `rotatedImage = imrotate(yourImage, angleOfRotation)`